# Maven ignores simplelogger.properties

Tags: maven, logging

If I launch

```
mvn clean
```

I am getting zero output, as if I demand only for WARNING only

But I have the default `simplelogger.properties` file:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.cacheOutputStream=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.levelInBrackets=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.Sisu=info
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.warnLevelString=WARNING
```

I have tried to put defaultLogLevel and warnLevelString to DEBUG, WARN( I had noticed difference in behaviour for that writing before) and info. But always I have the same zero output.

```
mvn -X
```

gives the correct debug level of output, but I don't need it, I need normal info level, and what is the most important, I want maven to behave up to the configuration. What could happen?

Restarts and Maven erasing and reinstalling were tried.

If I introduce into the project something that causes a warning, I see it in the output. The same for the error. It seems that Maven remembers somehow that logger was set to WARN level sometimes (and it really was) and cannot forget and change that state.

Answer (score 0):

I had set the

```
MAVEN_OPTS= -Dfile.defaultLogLevel="WARN"
```

It overcomes the settings in the `simplelogger.properties` file.